# Convert certain columns that are recurring to rows in postgres

Tags: postgresql, unpivot, greenplum

I have a table in Postgres that has ~50 million rows. I need to convert certain columns to rows.

[image]

I need to unpivot certain columns for individuals that repeat as an individual column and repeat the non-individual variables against the respective ID -

The following is the output I need -

[image]

Id appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Greenplum or Postgres? Although they share some common roots, they are quite different. In Postgres this would be easy, by using a lateral join against a `values` clause, e.g. like this: https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/unpivot-with-postgres/

Comment: with such a simple query, I would use UNION ALL

Comment: @JonRoberts - Yeah im concerned about the performance due to number of rows when using union all

Answer (score 0):

50 million rows is not a big deal in Greenplum but returning that many rows to a client is kind of pointless. I'm guessing you want to create a new table for this new output. You are also going to be creating a table that is 2x larger because you are taking a single row and turning it into 2.

```
create table new_table as
select id, mid_1 as mid, name_1 as name, age_1 as age, location
from your_table
union all
select id, mid_2 as mid, name_2 as name, age_2 as age, location
from your_table
distributed by (id);
```